# writing this with pygame in python 3.2 keep getting error: built_in_function_or_method object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

```
def message_to_screen(msg,color):
    screen_text = font.render(msg, True, color)
    gameDisplay.blit(screen_text, [display_width/2, display_height/2])
    #other code is here but I dont think its relevent
message_to_screen("You Lose", red)
time.sleep[2]
pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()       
quit()
#making a snake game in pygame
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the square brackets here:

```
time.sleep[2]
```

to parentheses:

```
time.sleep(2)
```